# Django: included login form reloading when there are errors

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'm building a Django app where I show a landing page if there's no user logged in, and I display the login form within that page. I've followed these [setup steps](https://realpython.com/django-user-management/) to get going, and then I added a context processor so I could display the login form within my landing page view, and I added it to the context_processors list in settings.py.

All of that is working great! I can successfully log someone in, or if I give a wrong password I get the message that the credentials aren't right.

**The problem:** in the case where I give a wrong password and fail authentication, the website reloads the login form on its own with the message to the user (so the user's going to another page). How I can display the error message from within that same landing page where the form is originally displayed?  (Note: I'm using the default Django authentication and haven't done anything yet to define any special behavior)

landing.html:

```
{% block content %}
    Some welcome message! 
    {% include "registration/login.html"%}
    
    Some other contents
{% endblock content %}
```

context_processors.py:

```
def include_login_form(request):
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return {'form': form}
```

Login.html:

```
{% extends 'familytree/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
  {% endif %}

  {% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
      please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
      <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

  <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Email address: </td>
        <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
  </form>
<a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot password?</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the url from the form action: <form method="post" action="">

Comment: thanks for the idea! When I try that, it *does* keep me on the same page, but then it no longer shows the error message that the username/password don't match :/  Then I also tried it with url 'landing', but same thing: I stay on the same page but the error text isn't shown